# Managing 400+ routes in Laravel with PhpStorm autocompletion

Tags: php, laravel, routes, phpstorm

I'm wondering how to deal with 400+ Routes.

We currently separate all the routes into multiple files according to the controller namespace they belong to.

The structure of `App/Http/Routes` looks something like this:

```
- Auth.php
- Marketing.php
- Orders.php
```

All our routes are named. But here comes the actual problem we are having.

Our routes are named by using Classes filled with Constants that define the route name.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Marketing;

class RouteConstants
{
    /**
     * MarketingController
     */
    const INDEX = 'marketing.index';
    const DISABLED = 'marketing.disabled';
```

These Constant Classes are located in the Controller namespace. They are then used in the `Marketing.php` routes file like so:

````
/**
 * Marketing Routes
 */
Route::group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Marketing'], function() {

    /**
     * MarketingController Routes
     */
    Route::get('marketing/overview', [
        'uses' => 'MarketingController@index',
        'as' => MarketingRoutes::INDEX
    ]);

    Route::get('marketing/disabled', [
        'uses' => 'MarketingController@showDisabled',
        'as' => MarketingRoutes::DISABLED
    ]);```
````

This is done because it allows us to use the PhpStorm autocomplete features and also see where each route is used.

But the problem with this is that we are using two systems at the same time. Laravel's internal routing naming system and at the same time we are using our own system defining the names as constants.

There must be a better way to manage this amount of routes and having a way to check for usages in the project files.

Currently it is also pretty messy in our views:

```
<a href="{{ route(App\Http\Controllers\Marketing\RouteConstants::INDEX) }}">Marketing</a>
```

I already tried the Laravel plugin for PhpStorm but this doesn't work properly when having a folder with routes that are automatically loaded into the `RouteServiceProvider`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noted in the changelog of the Laravel Plugin for PhpStorm (version 0.11), support was added for Laravel 5.3's routes structure.

I suggest you move the routes directory to the root directory of your project. Just like Laravel 5.3 has.
For example: `app/Http/Routes/` becomes `routes/`.

When useing version 0.11 of the plugin and you have the 5.3 folder structure I see no reason auto suggest for the route names wouldn't work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Tested it and it works. The only downside is that you can't see where your routes are being used in the application. I guess I will open a issue on the Laravel Phpstorm plugin to maybe add this functionality.

Comment: Opened a issue on the Laravel Phpstorm plugin https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-laravel-plugin/issues/85

Answer (score 1):

I think if you go as far as const in the controller the text would be shorter to just use the normal names. Then your views would be nicer again.

You could on the other side look in the docs at the Route::resource where your routes file will get much smaller as it auto sets up all crud routes and then passes responsibility to controller

Comment: Afaik and tested you still have to prefix the controller with the full namespace in the view. So I don't see how that would solve that issue. As far as `Route::resource` is concerned that would be preference. I'm not that bothered with my routes file becoming big in that sense. I rather like to have 1 way of defining routes. My main problem is the autocompleting and usage checking of routes.